# Cognos: Filtering after using aggregate function

Tags: report, business-intelligence, cognos, dimensional-modeling

I have a question regarding filtering after using aggregate function. The column "Gesamt" is aggregate with following Expression.

**Aggregate
(
currentMeasure within set 
(
lastPeriods 
(-1000; [01. JANUAR 2018])
)
)**

I aggregate the currentMeasure for the next 1000 days starting from the 1st January 2018. Now i would like to filter the Column "Gesamt" that only values > 10000 should be displayed. I have tried to set the filter directly in the Filtersection like [Gesamt] > 10000 and also with a prompt and both doesnt work, cause as soon as i start the Report i got the result that "no data is available".

I tried also both filter settings with before and after automatic aggregation.

[image]

Does anyone had the same Problem and know how to solve it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this out against 11.1 DQM DMR GoSales(analysis) and applying the following filter on the row edge of the crosstab (missing from your screen capture) appears to work for me.

filter([Sales (analysis)].[Products].[Products].[Product line],Aggregate ( currentMeasure within set ( lastPeriods (-1000, [20121231]) ) )>5000000)

Comment: Thank you i will try it out :)